# AgglomerativeClustering setting up distance_threshold

Tags: scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset and I want to use AgglomerativeClustering to find clusters.

I tried with some sample array, but not able to figure out how to set the distance_threshold. I thought of using this as I'm not aware of the number of clusters for similar set of data.

The sample code is as below.

```
corpus = ['Rose is a flower.', 'Apple is a fruit', 'Lily is a flower', 'Banana is a fruit', 'Jackfruit is a fruit', 'Mango is a fruit']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
transformer = FunctionTransformer(lambda x: X.todense(), accept_sparse=True)
X_dense = transformer.transform(X)
AG = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, distance_threshold =2, linkage='ward')
y_km = AG.fit_predict(X_dense)
```

My question is;

1. If I use distance_threshold as "2", I get all records in one cluster. If I use "1", I get six clusters. But if I select "1.5", I get 2 clusters; which for this example is correct.
   This was a sample data created, so I could play around and check for the correctness, but how this can be selected for a production kind of code?

Is there a better way of selecting distance_threshold ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this myself, without luck. So I'll put what I have found here, for the next searcher.

If `n_features, n_samples = X_dense.shape`, then I'd have thought that `distance_threshold` was relative to the maximum Euclidean distance in `X_dense`. For simplicity, if the features are normalized then that would be `sqrt(n_features)` (max distance 1 in each dimension).

However, that does not match the `AgglomerativeClustering` distances output. I have found the (I think) correct formula for maximum distance in the normalized case to be

```
max_dist = np.sqrt(n_features * (2 - 2/n_samples))
```

There's probably a good reason why it is so, but I don't know it.

With this, you can set `distance_threshold` to the more understandable `normalized_distance_threshold * max_dist`, with `normalized_distance_threshold=0` for single-sample clusters, `=1` for a single cluster.